# Regular expression for mathematical expression and logical with groups

Tags: php, regex

I have this Regular expression:

```
/(?:\-?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\.?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?+[\+\-\*\/\<\>\=])+\-?[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:\.?[0-9a-zA-Z]+)?/
```

The problem is  that I need the n's groups that this expression can decode, but I don't know how to change it.

I used https://regex101.com/ to edit, and removed the `?:` that caused the expression to no match correctly.

The regular input is like `1+2-b*4/c or 1+a=3-b`.

The answer that I need is like

```
full match[0] = 1+a=3-b

group[1] = '1'
group[2] = '+'
group[3] = 'a'
group[4] = '='
group[5] = '3'
group[6] = '-'
group[7] = 'b'
```

Comment: u can use 2 regex (ur regexp for validate and then "\d+" for get all group numbers).

Comment: no only single character, i use strings like "string" or number like 12 or 12.3, this regular expresion match this type of inputs but i  couldn't create the groups for operate later @chris85

Comment: @chris85, thx dude, that is exactly what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that expression quite a bit. Also note the only character in your character class that actually needed to be escaped was the `-`, and moving it to the first/last character has the same effect. This regex should accomplish what you are after:

```
[a-z]+|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[-+/*=]
```

That searches for continuous (at least 1) lowercase alpha characters, continuous numbers (with decimal possibility), or any (most?) mathematical operation. Since these a separate rules each find will be one match.

PHP Usage:

```
foreach(array('12.3+22-this*4/varable','1+a=3-b') as $equat) {
    preg_match_all('~[a-z]+|(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|[-+/*=]~', $equat, $matches);
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/727124

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/0mTL6d/1